# How to handle redundant cases in regex?

Tags: regex, parsing, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have to parse a file data into good and bad records the data should be of format

```
Patient_id::Patient_name (year of birth)::disease
```

The diseases are **pipe separated** and are selected from the following:

```
1.HIV
2.Cancer
3.Flu
4.Arthritis 
5.OCD
```

Example: 23::Alex.jr (1969)::HIV|Cancer|flu

The regex expression I have written is

```
\d*::[a-zA-Z]+[^\(]*\(\d{4}\)::(HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD) 
     (\|(HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD))*
```

But it's also considering the records with redundant entries

24::Robin (1980)::HIV|Cancer|Cancer|HIV

How to handle these kind of records and how to write a better expression if the list of diseases is very large.

Note: I am using hadoop maponly job for parsing  so give answer in context with java.

Comment: What should happen where there is a disease listed that is not in the list?

Comment: @Thefourthbird  When an unknown disease is listed it shall be treated as bad record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do is capture the last part with al the diseases in one group (named capturing group `disease`) and then use split to get the individual ones and then make the list unique.

`^\d*::[a-zA-Z]+[^\(]*\(\d{4}\)::(?<disease>(?:HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD)(?:\|(?:HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD))*)$`

For example:

```
String regex = "^\\d*::[a-zA-Z]+[^\\(]*\\(\\d{4}\\)::(?<disease>(?:HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD)(?:\\|(?:HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD))*)$";
String string = "24::Robin (1980)::HIV|Cancer|Cancer|HIV";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String[] parts =  matcher.group("disease").split("\\|");
    Set<String> uniqueDiseases = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(parts));
    System.out.println(uniqueDiseases);
}
```

Result:

```
[HIV, Cancer]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YLfGeM/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/NLOBoe)

Comment: It's not working for records I have 24::Robin (1980)::HIV|Cancer|Cancer|HIV";

Comment: @SrjSunny Is there content before the 24 and after the diseases? You can try this example without an `^` anchor. https://ideone.com/bSJB8o

Comment: It's not working for records I have=> 24::Robin (1980)::HIV|Cancer|Cancer|HIV23::Logan(1980)::HIV .. and so one. There are nearly 25 to 30 records in one line. And how to replace the unique diseases after finding them in the found string.

Comment: It worked after removing '^' and '$' but could you tell me why.

Comment: Those are anchors which assert the start and the end of the string. So if remove them the regex is not bound to those assertions and can also match the pattern inside a string.

Comment: the file i have contains 10M+ records , with bad records included so will removing anchors create any problem?

Comment: It is hard to judge that, but you could always make a copy and start with a small set to test it. If you remove the anchors `^$`, you could update the negated character class `[^\\(]*` to `[^\\(\\r\\n]*` to include newlines so that those will not be matched. [Demo](https://ideone.com/EEIuI4)

Answer (score 0):

You need the **negative lookahead**.
Try using this regex: `^\d*::[^(]+?\s*\(\d{4}\)::(?!.*(HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD).*\|\1)((HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD)(\||$))+$`.

Explanation:

1. The initial string `^\d*::[^(]+?\s*\(\d{4}\)::` is just an optimized one to match **Alex.jr** example (your version did not respect any non-alphabetic symbols in names)
2. The negative lookahead block `(?!.*(HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD).*\|\1)` stands for *"look forth for any disease name, encountered twice, and reject the string, if found any*. Its distinctive feature is the `(?! ... )` signature.
3. Finally, `((HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD)(\||$))+$` is also an optimized version of your block `(HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD)(\|(HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD))*`, oriented to avoid redundant listing.

Comment: It's worth noting that this check may fail if some disease in the list is a complete substing of another one (e.g. "Cancer" and "Lung Cancer"), but this also can be handled useng correct enclosures around listing sections

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easier to maintain method is that you use a bit changed regex,
like below:

```
^\d*::[a-zA-Z.]+\s\(\d{4}\)::((?:HIV|Cancer|flu|Arthritis|OCD|\|(?!\|))+)$
```

It contains:

- `^` and `$` anchors (you want that the **entire** string is matched,
  not its part).
- A capturing group, including a repeated non-capturing group (a container
  for alternatives). One of these alternatives is `|`, but with a negative
  lookahead for immediately following `|` (this way you disallow 2 or
  more consecutive `|`).

Then, if this regex matched for a particular row, you should:

- Split group No 1 by `|`.
- Check resulting string array for uniqueness (it should not contain
  repeating entries).

Only if this check succeeds, you should accept the row in question.